# TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null in react

Tags: reactjs

error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
    at babaClick (:75:17)
If i type it in ES5 it won't be wrong but if i type it in es6 just like the following code it's wrong .I just don't know why...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HelloMessage</title>
<script src="lib/react.js"></script>
<script src="lib/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="lib/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    class HelloMesssage extends  React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state={
                zan:0
            }

        }
        addZan(){
            this.setState(
                    {
                        zan:this.state.zan+1
                    }
            )
        }
        render(){
            return(
                    <div>
                        <p>姓名：{this.props.name}</p>
                        <p>赞：<Zan zan={this.state.zan}/></p>
                        <p><Btn babaZan={this.addZan.bind(this)}/></p>
                    </div>
            )
        }
    }
    class Btn extends  React.Component{
        babaClick(){
            this.props.babaZan();
        }
        render(){
            return(
                    <button onClick={this.babaClick}>赞</button>
            )
        }

    }
    class Zan extends  React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                    <span>{this.props.zan}</span>
            )
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
            <HelloMesssage name="xxxindy"/>,
            document.getElementById('container')
    );
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Btn` class below, you should add `.bind(this)` with the onClick handler as you did in the `HelloMesssage` class like `babaZan={this.addZan.bind(this)}`.

Hence, the onClick will become like `onClick={this.babaClick.bind(this)}` as below.

*Note*: In `ES6`, it needs `.bind(this)` whereas in `ES5`, this is not required.

```
class Btn extends  React.Component{
        babaClick(){
            this.props.babaZan();
        }
        render(){
            return(
                    <button onClick={this.babaClick.bind(this)}>赞</button>
            )
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `babaClick(){ this.props.babaZan(); }` to an arrow function in order for it to know what "this" is: `babaClick = () => { this.props.babaZan(); }`